# how to pass a Ruby iterator as a parameter?

Tags: ruby, block, yield

I'd like to write a method that yields values in one place and pass it as a parameter to another method that will invoke it with a block.  I'm convinced it can be done but somehow I'm not able to find the right syntax.

Here's some sample (non-working) code to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
def yielder
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
end

def user(block)
  block.call { |x| puts x }
end

# later...
user(&yielder)
```

---

```
$ ruby x.rb
x.rb:2:in `yielder': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
from x.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

---

FWIW, in my real code, yielder and user are in different classes.

---

**Update**

Thanks for your answers.  As Andrew Grimm mentioned, I want the iterator method to take parameters.  My original example left this detail out.  This snippet provides an iterator that counts up to a given number.  To make it work, I made the inner block explicit.  It does what I want, but it's a bit ugly. If anyone can improve on this I'd be very interested in seeing how.

```
def make_iter(upto)
  def iter(upto, block)
    (1 .. upto).each do |v|
      block.call(v)
    end
  end
  lambda { |block| iter(upto, block) }
end

def user(obj)
  obj.call Proc.new { |x| puts x }
end

# later...
user(make_iter(3))
```

Comment: Well, a working sample would be way better.

Comment: @Tass: I think the code epicsmile's shown is adequate for our purposes.

Comment: After some experimentation with the help of answers already given, I came up with a working example and added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't use a lambda or unbound method, but it is the simplest way to go...

```
def f
  yield 1
  yield 2
end

def g x
  send x do |n|
    p n
  end
end

g :f
```

Comment: I like the minimalist approach.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `&yielder`, you're calling `yielder` and then trying to apply the `&` (convert-to-Proc) operator on the result. Of course, calling `yielder` without a block is a no-go. What you want is to get a reference to the method itself. Just change that line to `user(method :yielder)` and it will work.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Based on that specification and nothing else, it's hard to say what the best way would be. The obvious route would be having `user` pass the appropriate arguments at call time, just like any other method call. If `user` takes a method with no arguments and we want to pass a method that does take arguments, then we'd better know what arguments need to be passed. In that case, we can create a wrapper function like `user(lambda {|&block| yielder(some_argument, &block)}`.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: good catch.  I did underspecify my requirements.  I do indeed want a yielder that is flexible.  I don't want user() to have to know about any arguments for yielder() -- the idea is that it's an opaque iterator.  I'm thinking I could build a proc with a closure to capture the right values and then pass that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be along the lines of what you want to do:

```
def yielder
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
end

def user(meth)
  meth.call { |x| puts x }
end

# later...
user( Object.method(:yielder) )
```

Some related info here: http://blog.sidu.in/2007/11/ruby-blocks-gotchas.html

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out the baseline problem is that when you try to pass a function as a parameter Ruby executes it – as a side effect of parenthesis being optional.

I liked the simplicity of the symbol method that was mentioned before, but I would be afraid of my future self forgetting that one needs to pass the iterator as a symbol to make that work. Being readability a desired feature, you may then wrap your iterator into an object, which you can pass around without fear of having code unexpectedly executed.

**Anonymous object as iterator**

That is: using an anonymous object with just one fuction as iterator. Pretty immediate to read and understand. But due to the restrictions in the way Ruby handles scope the iterator cannot easily receive parameters: any parameters received in the function `iterator` are not automatically available within `each`.

```
def iterator
    def each
        yield("Value 1")
        yield("Value 2")
        yield("Value 3")
    end
end

def iterate(my_iterator)
    my_iterator.each do |value|
        puts value
    end
end

iterate iterator
```

**Proc object as iterator**

Using a `Proc` object as iterator lets you easily use any variables passed to the *iterator constructor*. The dark side: this starts looking weird. Reading the `Proc.new` block is not immediate for the untrained eye. Also: not being able to use `yield` makes it a bit uglier IMHO.

```
def iterator(prefix:)
    Proc.new { |&block|
        block.call("#{prefix} Value 1")
        block.call("#{prefix} Value 2")
        block.call("#{prefix} Value 3")
    }
end

def iterate(my_iterator)
    my_iterator.call do |value|
        puts value
    end
end

iterate iterator(prefix: 'The')
```

**Lambda as iterator**

Ideal if you want to obfuscate your code so hard that no one else besides you can read it.

```
def iterator(prefix:)
    -> (&block) {
        block.call("#{prefix} Value 1")
        block.call("#{prefix} Value 2")
        block.call("#{prefix} Value 3")
    }
end

def iterate(my_iterator)
    my_iterator.call do |value|
        puts value
    end
end

iterate iterator(prefix: 'The')
```

**Class as iterator**

And finally the good ol' OOP approach. A bit verbose to initialize for my taste, but with little or none surprise effect.

```
class Iterator
    def initialize(prefix:)
        @prefix = prefix
    end

    def each
        yield("#{@prefix} Value 1")
        yield("#{@prefix} Value 2")
        yield("#{@prefix} Value 3")
    end
end

def iterate(my_iterator)
    my_iterator.each do |value|
        puts value
    end
end

iterate Iterator.new(prefix: 'The')
```